# Concatenate a string with a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I have a string called `value` and a string called `s` that contains a URL such as `http://`. I would like to change the value `s` into a hyperlink such as `<a href="' + s + '"> Read More</a>` and then add the new string into the variable `value`. However when I try `value = value + "<a href="' + s + '"> Read More</a>";` I get an error `Syntax error in module 'script': SyntaxError value = value + " Read More"; ^^^^^^^^^ SyntaxError: Unexpected string`.

How can I add the hyperlink to the string of text?

Comment: Can you post the complete script and any related HTML?

Comment: It's just a typo with your quotes. Look at them more closely. Voting to close as typo/non-repro.

Comment: The problem is caused by the single quotes `'`. Try to remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value = value + "<a href="' + s + '"> Read More</a>"` This is indeed invalid. You have two extra `'` outside, they should be inside.

Should be `value = value + "<a href='" + s + "'> Read More</a>";`

Or in ES6 :

```
value = `${value}<a href='${s}'>Read More</a>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with openinq/closing quotes -

It should be -

```
value = value + "<a href='" + s + "'> Read More</a>";
```

Note how individual strings start and end with doubule quote " and internal one - the value of href starts and ends with single quote '